# Python - Sublime Text and Requests module

Tags: python, sublime-text-3

Environment:

- MacBook Pro running MacOS Catalina, Version 10.15 (19A583)
- Python 3.7.3
- Sublime Text 3, Version 3.2.2, Build 3211

I have installed the requests package using pip install and pip3 install. For good measure, I installed the package both as sudo and non-sudo. The package appears when I run the pip list command in Terminal and I can see it in the expect directory using Finder (/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages). In Terminal, I can run python3 and import requests. I can import and utilize requests in PyCharm CE and Jupyter. I cannot, however, access it Sublime. When trying to execute import requests, I consistently get the error: "ImportError: No module named requests."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same problem.

I can import requests from the command line but not in sublime, it seems sublime is using a different version that python3 on the command line. (3.7.3 instead of 3.7.4 which I can get working in the terminal).

To fix I changed my sublime build file from python3 to

```
{
    "cmd": ["**/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3**", "-u", "$file"], 
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)", "selector": "source.python" 
}
```

I should note python was installed via home-brew.